# How can I distinguish read and write events on the same socket?

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

I'm using `epoll` to get notifications about incoming data. It's not hard because all events returned by `epoll_wait()` indicates, that I can read data from `epoll_event.data.fd` (socket descriptor).

But now I want get both types of notification: receiving and sending (socket is available for send). But I can't to do it because:

1. `epoll_event.events` which is returned by `epoll_wait()` is the same as I pass in `epoll_ctl()`. So it contains both `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLOUT` in my case.
2. Also if i trying to twice add one socket in `epoll` (as EPOLLIN and as EPOLLOUT event) I'll get a `EEXIST`.

How can I solve this problem without manually calling `select()` every time I get notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man epoll_wait` clearly states that "the events member will contain the returned event bit field.". Therefore, if you are getting `EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT` in `epoll_event.events`, then your socket must be ready for both reading and writing.

If you only want to be notified when the socket *changes state*, use `EPOLLET` for edge-triggered operation.

Answer (score 5):

When you add a descriptor using `epoll_ctl`, set the `events` mask to be `EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT`.

When you get notifications via `epoll_wait` then you'd loop through the returned notifications checking for `EPOLLIN` and `EPOLLOUT`.

**Pseudo code**:

```
int index, count;
count = epoll_wait(epfd, epoll_event, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
for (index = 0; index < count; ++index) {
  if (epoll_event[index].events & EPOLLIN) {
    // Ready for read
  }

  if (epoll_event[index].events & EPOLLOUT) {
    // Ready for write
  }
}
```

Some people only set the `EPOLLOUT` bit when they have data present in their send buffer. I did not include any error checking.